# AsyncIO - How to test if my function is blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test if I'm correctly using an asyncio library (aiofiles) to see if its blocking.

How can I do this? My idea was to have an infinite loop of asyncio.sleep checking the delay between each call, while I try to insert a blocking call in between

This is my current try, but `blocking` is never called, I'm assuming the problem is that the infinite loop is actually also blocking.

```
from asyncio import sleep, get_event_loop
import time


async def test_blocking():
  while True:
    timea = time.time()
    await sleep(1)
    timeb = time.time() - timea
    delay = timeb - 1.00
    if delay >= 0.01:
      print(f'Function blocked by {delay}s')

async def blocking():
  print('Running blocking function')
  time.sleep(5)


loop = get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_blocking())
loop.run_until_complete(blocking())
```

Comment: async programming is based on cooperation between tasks. The scheduling isn't preemptive. So if your function blocks, everything else does as well (and viceversa, as you guessed correctly)

Comment: You say to run `test_blocking` until it's complete. It has a while loop with no break or return. It will never complete, blocking any code after `loop.run_until_complete(test_blocking())` from ever running.

Answer (score 7):

Your `test_blocking` coroutine is not actually blocking the event loop - it's implemented correctly. However, `run_until_complete` is a blocking call. So your script is never actually making it to the `run_until_complete(blocking())` line - it's waiting for `test_blocking` to return, which never happens because it's an infinite loop. Use [`loop.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) instead, and you'll see the behavior you expect.

Also, you may want to consider using [`asyncio`'s debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode) to achieve what you're trying to do here. When enabled, it can alert you when a particular callback takes longer than a given amount of time:

> Callbacks taking longer than 100ms are logged. The
> `loop.slow_callback_duration` attribute can be used to set the minimum
> execution duration in seconds that is considered “slow”.

When enabled on your test script, it prints this:

```
Executing <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<blocking() done, defined at a.py:13> result=None created at /home/dan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:595> took 5.005 seconds
```